# Electron-Builder Updater Just Uninstalls the current installation

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I am making an app with Electron and I was using Electron Builder with GitHub Releases to make updates to my app. I am using Electron Updater v4.0.6 to make the updates. 
It was working previously but now I don't know why but after I have installed the app, it checks for the update and even notifies me that I have an update. I have this code in my main.js:

```js
app.on('ready', function()  {
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
});
```

The other parts are totally similar to what is given on the GitHub example: 
https://github.com/iffy/electron-updater-example

The app starts and then it closes. Accordingly, it should install the update but it doesn't. It starts old-uninstaller.exe an uninstalls the current installation, rendering the updating useless.

The logs didn't provide any information. They were normal as usual:

> [2019-01-14 00:35:15.771] [info] App starting...
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:15.880] [info] Checking for update
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:15.984] [info] Checking for update...
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:19.263] [info] Found version 0.0.2-alpha
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:19.263] [info] Good News! Update is Available.
>   Preparing to Download...
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:19.264] [info] Downloading update from
>   setup-0.0.2-alpha.exe
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:19.291] [info] No cached update info available
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:19.549] [info] Download block maps.
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:22.299] [info] File has 869 changed blocks
>
> [2019-01-14 00:35:22.303] [info] Full: 58,310.86 KB, To download:
>   18,792.45 KB (32%)
>
> [2019-01-14 00:36:12.565] [info] Update has finished downloading!
>   Restart to AutoInstall.
>
> [2019-01-14 00:36:18.990] [info] Auto install update on quit
>
> [2019-01-14 00:36:18.992] [info] Install: isSilent: true,
>   isForceRunAfter: false

I can't seem to get what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

`electron-updater` v4.0 and higher requires Electron 3 or later, please check electron version, then try updating your `electron-builder` to latest version:

> 4.0.0
>
> **BREAKING CHANGES**
>
> Requires Electron 3 or later. Cache directory changed, so, full download will be performed on update instead of
> differential.

Reference: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/electron-updater/CHANGELOG.md#400

Comment: This does not work. I am currently on newest versions of everythign electron related and my updating doesn't work. It only uninstalls the app and nothing else happens.